# Can't Pass Array into UBO

Tags: c, glsl, vulkan

I'm trying to initialize a setup in Vulkan where within the Shader there is a uniform array of textures and an corresponding arrays for the textures Width and Heights:

```
layout(binding=0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 model; //4x4 array of floats for uniform rotation and positioning
    uint texW[32]; //Widths of ith texture
    uint texH[32]; //Heights of ith texture

} ubo;
```

For some reason the shader only reads the mat4 and the first index of the texW. Everything else is initialized to 0.

Here's the Uniform Buffer Setup Code, for reference

```
void createUniformBuffers() {
    /**Uniform Buffer for View Transformation*/
    VkDeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(uniformBufferObject);

    uniformBuffers = malloc(swapChainSize * sizeof(VkBuffer));
    uniformBuffersMemory = malloc(swapChainSize * sizeof (VkDeviceMemory));
    
    for(uint i = 0; i < swapChainSize; i++)
        createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, &uniformBuffers[i], &uniformBuffersMemory[i]);
}

void createDescriptorPool() {
    VkDescriptorPoolSize poolSizes[4];
    poolSizes[0].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
    poolSizes[0].descriptorCount = swapChainSize;

    poolSizes[1].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
    poolSizes[1].descriptorCount = swapChainSize;

    VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo poolInfo;
    poolInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_POOL_CREATE_INFO;
    poolInfo.pNext = 0;
    poolInfo.flags = 0;
    poolInfo.poolSizeCount = 2;
    poolInfo.pPoolSizes = poolSizes;
    poolInfo.maxSets = swapChainSize;

    if(vkCreateDescriptorPool(lDevice, &poolInfo, 0, & descriptorPool)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create Descriptor Pool\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void createDescriptorSets() {
    VkDescriptorSetLayout layouts[swapChainSize];
    for(uint i = 0; i < swapChainSize; i++) layouts[i] = descriptorSetLayout;

    VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo  allocInfo;
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.pNext = 0;
    allocInfo.descriptorPool = descriptorPool;
    allocInfo.descriptorSetCount = swapChainSize;
    allocInfo.pSetLayouts = layouts;

    descriptorSets = malloc(sizeof(VkDescriptorSet) * swapChainSize);
    if(vkAllocateDescriptorSets(lDevice, &allocInfo, descriptorSets) ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to allocate descriptor sets\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(uint i = 0; i < swapChainSize; i++) {

        VkDescriptorBufferInfo  bufferInfo;
        bufferInfo.buffer = uniformBuffers[i];
        bufferInfo.offset = 0;
        bufferInfo.range = VK_WHOLE_SIZE; //sizeof(uniformBufferObject);



        VkWriteDescriptorSet descriptorWrites[2];

        descriptorWrites[0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
        descriptorWrites[0].pNext =  0;
        descriptorWrites[0].dstSet = descriptorSets[i];
        descriptorWrites[0].dstBinding = 0;
        descriptorWrites[0].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
        descriptorWrites[0].descriptorCount = 1;
        descriptorWrites[0].pBufferInfo = &bufferInfo;
        descriptorWrites[0].pImageInfo = 0;
        descriptorWrites[0].pTexelBufferView = 0;
        descriptorWrites[0].dstArrayElement = 0;


        VkDescriptorImageInfo imageInfo;
        imageInfo.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
        imageInfo.imageView = textureImageView[0];
        imageInfo.sampler= textureSampler;

        descriptorWrites[1].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
        descriptorWrites[1].pNext = 0;
        descriptorWrites[1].dstBinding = 1;
        descriptorWrites[1].dstSet = descriptorSets[i];
        descriptorWrites[1].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
        descriptorWrites[1].descriptorCount = 1;
        descriptorWrites[1].pImageInfo = &imageInfo;
        descriptorWrites[1].pBufferInfo = 0;
        descriptorWrites[1].pTexelBufferView = 0;
        descriptorWrites[1].dstArrayElement = 0;
        
        vkUpdateDescriptorSets(lDevice, 2, descriptorWrites,0,0);

    }

}
```

Here's the code where the uniformBuffer is updated,

```
void updateUniformBuffer(uint currentImage) {
    //FTR, I know I probably shouldn't remap each update, optimizing this is on my todo-list
    vkMapMemory(lDevice, uniformBuffersMemory[currentImage], 0, sizeof(uniformBufferObject), 0, (void*) &uData);
    memcpy(uData, &uniformData, sizeof(uniformBufferObject));
    


    memset(uData->model, 0, sizeof(uData->model));

    
    //Rotating the View, GLSL acknowledges this data
    uData->model[2][2] = uData->model[3][3] = 1;
    uData->model[0][0] = cosf(angle);
    uData->model[0][1] = -sinf(angle);
    uData->model[1][1] = cosf(angle);
    uData->model[1][0] = sinf(angle);
    angle+= 0.05f;

    uData->texW[0] = 1024; //<-------GLSL Vertex Shader will acknowledge this =)
    uData->texH[0] = 1024; //<-------GLSL Vertex Shader will ignore this  =(
    uData->texH[0] = 1024; //<-------GLSL Vertex Shader will also ignore this >_<

    vkUnmapMemory(lDevice,uniformBuffersMemory[currentImage]);}
```

Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What memory type is used to back the buffer? Do you need to add `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges()`? What memory barriers do you have when reading the resource in the pipeline (i.e. is something doing srcStage = HOST_WRITE_BIT)?

Comment: @solidpixel I'm using memory type of VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT (assuming that's what you were referring to). The data structure is directly mapped to the Uniform VkBuffer, so I'm not sure that vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges would be needed, but I could be wrong. I'll try it out.

Comment: @VKGuy99: I don't know what type `uData` is. Can you show its definition and the steps you took to ensure that it matches the GLSL uniform buffer layout? Because if you didn't take any steps, then I'm pretty sure it doesn't.

Comment: If you have coherent memory, vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges shouldn't be required.